# ASP.NET Web API - Handle more requests per second

Tags: c#, performance, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET Web API to design a REST API and hosted it as a Cloud App on Azure.
I used the Load testing framework [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/test/performance-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-performance-testing?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), to test the performance.

I find for 100 concurrent requests, the average response time is as expected. But when the number of concurrent users increases further,  the Average Response Time also increases.

NOTE : The Response time for a single request is ~3 seconds.

I tried making my POST call async , but that wasn't of much use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe those are the physical limitations of your network and there isn't much you can do there.

Comment: You might want to scale up your cloud app. See this : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-scale/